# Compile with "Listable" only on one argument

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, compile

I would like to write a Compiled function which is listable only in the first argument, because this allow fast and easy parallelization. How is it possible to do it?

In the following way it does not work

```
Compile[{{tt, _Real, 0}, {eVal0, _Complex, 1}, {eVec0, _Complex, 
   2}, {nf, _Integer, 0}, {dx, _Real, 0}},(...),CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

Comment: Probably, this gets solved by increasing the ranks of all the other argument arrays by `1`. But it is hard to say without a concrete example.

Comment: I would very much like to answer this question, but as Henrik too, I'm not sure I understand the problem of the OP. In general, you can use a listable, compiled function and call it in a way that it is only parallelized for one argument. But to be certain, we need a concrete example and more information.